# unresolved external symbol "unsigned long gVar"

Tags: c++

I have a `static unsigned long gVar;` which is global declared in server.cc file.
But when i try to use it in other file using `extern unsigned long gVar;` , it gives error :

`unresolved external symbol "unsigned long gVar"`. Can you please tell me how to extern a static variable, as i am able to extern other variables from that file except this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use `static` and `extern` together.
If you want to use the variable in other files just remove the `static` and just declare it as `extern`.

**Why you cannot use `static` and `extern` together?**

`static` implies Internal linkage, while `extern` implies External linkage.

**Internal Linkage** means that the symbol is accessible only in the Translation unit in which it was declared, while **External Linkage** implies the symbol should be visible in all files accross your project, clearly, they are mutually exclusive.

Comment: @DanO: My answer only intends to explain the Q being actually asked, i.e: *Why a `static` variable cannot be declared as `extern`?* & I do not intend to obfuscate it by adding details which are important but yet irrelevant to the Q at hand.

Comment: But he doesn't make the distinction between a static local vs. a static member, this leaves some ambiguity in both the question and the answers.

Comment: @DanO: OP clearly specify's: *I have a `static unsigned long gVar;` **which is global declared in `server.cc` file***, probably, You missed that.I don't see any ambiguity here.

Comment: But the *reason* that he is confused is that he doesn't understand that static identifies his variable as file scope. It would have been useful to explain the different uses of the static keyword to completely clear up his confusion. If he knew what the various uses of the static keyword were he would not have asked his question... anyway.. it doesn't matter, obviously he's satisfied with the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Well, an object defined as `static T x;` at namespace scope is visible only locally in the file where it is defined. In fact, this is precisely the function of using the `static` keyword (at namespace level). Just remove the `static`.